# How to perform update operation in JSP

Tags: oracle, jsp, sql-update

I have been learning JSP for about a week and trying to do an update operation in a sample contact us table. I am using oracle 10g as backend.
Here is editmsg.jsp which selects the particular record to be updated. I have "select by name" instead of ID.

```
 <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Edit page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
       <form action="asave.jsp">
     <%
         String n=request.getParameter("val");

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","system");
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from contactus where name ='"+n+"'");
while(rs.next()){
//con.close();
%>


            <table><tr> <td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="aname" value="<%=rs.getString("name")%>"></td></tr>

            <tr> <td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="aemail" value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"></td></tr>
            <tr> <td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="aphone" value="<%=rs.getString(3)%>"></td></tr>
            <tr> <td>Message:</td><td><input type="text" name="amessage" value="<%=rs.getString(4)%>"></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td><td><input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick='javascript:window.location='Home.jsp';'></td></tr>
            </table>
            <%} %>


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

If submit button is clicked it should perform the update function
asave.jsp

```
String aname=request.getParameter("val");
String aemail=(String)session.getAttribute("aemail");
Integer aphone=(Integer)session.getAttribute("aphone");
String amessage=(String)session.getAttribute("amessage");
System.out.print(aname);

try{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","system");

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("update contactus set email=?,phone=?,message=? where name='"+aname+"'");
ps.setString(1,aemail);
ps.setInt(2,aphone);
ps.setString(3,amessage);
ps.executeQuery();
con.close();
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

%>
<jsp:forward page="messages.jsp"></jsp:forward>
```

Wen i click submit,instead of getting updated record details, it stay the same.BTW, I tried executeUpdate() as well. It did not work.
Please help..

Comment: where you are getting the old record details ?

Comment: I mean all the contact details are getting displayed on messages.jsp page in table form. After clicking update, its not showing updated record in table. In other words,the record does not get updated in database

Comment: you definitely have to use the method executeUpdate() instead of executeQuery(). Why don't you want to use servlets and use jsp only for displaying purposes?

Comment: No offense intended,Why do you guys reply with questions? Like I mentioned in my question,I'm experimenting with jsp at the moment. That's why i want to know how to do this stuff.I did use executeUpdate() method, but it did not work. Conventionally, like zaratustra mentioned,jsp is used for presentation purposes. But I want to learn how to use jdbc in jsp as well. Thats why.I would appreciate if you guys could post solutions.

Comment: Guys, Pls help me...I'm counting on you..